How to improve OCR accuracy using Pytesseract and describe preprocessing steps?
This code
I've implemented a preprocessing pipeline before applying OCR. This includes converting images to grayscale, applying a sharpening filter, and binarizing using Otsu's thresholding method. Here's a simplified version of my preprocessing code:
# Preprocessing steps
def preprocess_image(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    sharpened = cv2.filter2D(gray, -1, kernel)
    _, binary = cv2.threshold(sharpened, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    return binary


My input images and the images between preprocessing stages are as follows



As evident , these pre-processing steps is not helping the model with OCR.
I would appreciate it if someone could recommend preprocessing steps to get better OCR results.
I have tried to above preprocessing steps.

I don't think your original image is bad enough that preprocessing will help. Do you get poor results from no preprocessing?

Yes . Without preprocessing the results arent that great either @NickODell

What results do you get?

@NickODell  something like this ,
‘Parameter [Value
‘Dats object number 000 Data object sizes Lognomal dist_@mean 18 KBy Data access probabilities —| Zip dist. with parameter 1 ‘Cache replacement scheme | AE
‘Cache capacity 0.01 = S~ object size
‘Object fetch delay Exponeaual dist wih = 23 “Transcoding rate 30 KBhce
Client number 1000,
Cell residence tne Exp. dis with @ = 40 minwies Cell holding time Exp. dist. with jz = 15 minutes Cell etublnhing me Exp. dist. with j= one hour
note i have a seperate logic to seperate it out into columns which works
